# Is there a class of mathematical structures with non-isomorphic natural representations as a standard Borel space?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, mathematical-philosophy

**Background.** The field of Borel equivalence relation theory
provides a robust, unifying theory that organizes most of the
classification problems of classical mathematics into a hierarchy,
allowing us precisely to compare their relative difficulty.
Namely, every such classification problem amounts to an
equivalence relation on a class of mathematical structures, and
one can generally present the class of structures as a standard
Borel space. An equivalence relation $E$ on such a space *reduces*
to another $F$, if there is a Borel function $f$ for which
$$x\mathrel{E}y\quad\iff\quad f(x)\mathrel{F} f(y).$$ Thus, the classification problem of $E$ is reduced to that of $F$, and a rich hierarchy has emerged. Anyone with a classification problem in any part of
mathematics should seek to situate it into this hierarchy. The
subject is a pleasing mix of ideas from many parts of mathematics.

**The issue.** Since the hierarchy works essentially on coded versions of the classification problems as standard Borel spaces, it is important for the subject that these encodings are authentic. Su Gao discussed the importance of this issue in his
book,
[Invariant descriptive set theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfiOZWY282QC&q=328&f=false#v=snippet&q=328&f=false) (p. 328),
where he proposed the following principle:

> **Gao's thesis.** For any collection $H$ of mathematical
>   structures and natural standard Borel structures $B_1$ and $B_2$
>   on $H$, there is a Borel isomorphism $\psi:\langle
> H,B_1\rangle\cong\langle H,B_2\rangle$ for which $\psi(x)$ is
>   isomorphic to $x$ for every $x\in H$.

In other words, all natural presentations of a given class of
mathematical structures as a standard Borel space are the same up
to Borel isomorphism. Many instances of such isomorphisms have been observed, and empirical evidence is accumulating in support of the thesis.

In his dissertation, Burak Kaya formulates the principle as asserting: for any class $H$ of mathematical structures, if $\langle X,B_1\rangle$ and $\langle Y,B_2\rangle$ are two standard Borel spaces naturally encoding the structures of $H$, then there is a Borel isomorphism $\psi:X\to Y$ such that the structures in $H$ coded by $x$ and by $\psi(x)$ are isomorphic. It is this formulation of the thesis that seems to arise more often in practice, as researchers give different encodings of their class of structures.

Gao discusses the philosophical nature of his thesis, citing
specifically the difficulty of the issue of what counts as
natural. He describes the thesis as an analogue of the
Church/Turing thesis in computability theory.

**The questions.** My view is that Gao's thesis is critically
important for the subject, because if as we desire we are to view
the results of Borel equivalence relation theory as being about
the actual classification problems arising in mathematics, we need
to know that we have successfully captured those problems in our
presentations of them as standard Borel spaces.

In the case of computability theory, Turing in his famous paper
gave a forceful philosophical argument that in principle any
effective means of computation can be simulated by Turing
machines. In the case of Gao's thesis, however, we seem to lack
comparable forceful philosophical grounds. So are the two theses analogous?

I'd like to get a grasp on the nature of possible counterexamples
to Gao's thesis, if there might be any. Presumably, if we weaken
the naturality requirement, we can find counterexamples to the
thesis. How unnatural do the counterexamples have to be? Can anyone provide me with *unnatural* counterexamples?

**Question 1.** What are examples of collections $H$ of
mathematical structures that have almost-natural standard Borel
structures $B_1$ and $B_2$ on $H$, with no Borel isomorphism
respecting isomorphism of structures in $H$?

In other words, how close to natural can we get while violating the conclusion of Gao's thesis? It seems important for us to be aware of the range of possibility when discussing this thesis.

**Question 2.** What are the philosophical grounds that we have in
support of Gao's thesis?

I became interested in the issue of Gao's thesis because it arose
in the recent dissertation and [dissertation defense of Burak Kaya](http://jdh.hamkins.org/burak-kaya/),
where we had an interesting discussion about it during the
question session.

Comment: It seems to me that one might make a counterexample for which there is no isomorphism between $B_1$ and $B_2$ as desired, but where there is a Borel multi-function providing the desired association.

Comment: Would you be able to briefly describe an example or two of the kind of isomorphism that Gao's thesis is talking about?

Comment: Many examples arise from different methods of encoding structures as elements of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. For example, you might view a countable group by thinking of the group operation as a trinary relation on $\mathbb{N}$, leading you to view the collection of groups as a certain Borel subspace of $2^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$, which therefore has a standard Borel structure. But there are other natural ways to represent a group operations as a standard Borel space, and they will be Borel isomorphic.

Comment: In some cases, discussed in Gao's book, the proof of Borel isomorphism is not immediate.

Comment: @NateEldredge: One example that actually was in my thesis is the following. A minimal subshift is a pair of the form $(O,\sigma)$ where $O$ is an infinite closed $\sigma$-invariant subset of $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$, $\sigma$ is the left-shif map and $\sigma$-orbit of every point is dense. You can form the standard Borel space of such $O$'s as a subspace of the Polish space $K(2^{\mathbb{Z}})$ consisting of compact subsets of $2^{\mathbb{Z}}$ (where the standard Borel structure is coming from the Hausdorff metric). On the other hand, each such $O$ has to be homeomorphic to the Cantor set++

Comment: @NateEldredge: ++ and after forming a topologically conjugate system $(2^{\mathbb{N}}, \varphi)$, we can code this system by an automorphism of $\mathbb{B}$, where $\mathbb{B}$ denotes the Boolean algebra of clopen subsets of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. This means that you can also form the space of (infinite) minimal subshifts as a subspace of $\mathbb{B}^{\mathbb{B}}$. On the other hand, there exist Borel maps between these spaces that map objects to objects coding isomorphic structures.

Comment: @Burak, it seems that Gao states the principle a little differently than you did in your dissertation, since he is talking about standard Borel structures on the same set $H$, whereas many of the examples I know are really about having different encodings of $H$ inside other standard Borel spaces. But I guess it is the same issue at bottom.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Yes. That is exactly why I wrote that I am slightly changing the phrasing while quoting him. The hyperspaces he is referring to (such as the hyperspace of all Polish metric spaces) are mostly proper classes, not sets. This means that we have to do some kind of "coding" to make our standard Borel spaces be defined on sets. (For example, identifying countable groups with countable groups whose underlying sets are $\mathbb{N}$ is essentially a "coding".) I think the general version I quote in the dissertation is more appropriate.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with you!

Comment: Another example:  shall we think of a countable linear order as a binary relation on $\mathbb{N}$, or as a suborder of $\mathbb{Q}$? These are two different ways to think about how to put a standard Borel structure on the collection of countable linear orders.

Comment: For the given motivation, wouldn't it be sufficient to show that the isomorphism relation with respect to the first standard Borel structure is Borel bireducible to itself with respect to the second standard Borel structure? I think that it is possible to argue for this much weaker version of the thesis.

Comment: @AndreKornell I think that is right. Nevertheless, my questions would arise also with that weaker principle. While it seems to be true in all the particular cases that seem to arise, are there unnatural or almost-natural counterexamples?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but here is what seems to be a counterexample (Lemma 9.2.2 from Su Gao [Invariant Descriptive Set Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfiOZWY282QC&q=328&f=false#v=snippet&q=328&f=false)):

Let $H$ be the class of countable well-orders. The first Borel representation will be $(\mathbb{R}, F_{\omega_1})$ where $a F_{\omega_1} b$ iff $\omega_1^{CK(a)} = \omega_1^{CK(b)}$. The second is $(LO, E_{\omega_1})$, where $LO$ is the subset of $\mathcal{P}(\omega \times \omega)$ that encode linear orders of $\omega$, and $\phi E_{\omega_1} \psi$ iff either they are both non-wellordered, or they are both well-ordered of the same rank.

Both of these have $\omega_1$-many classes, so can be used to represent classes of $H$ (for $E_{\omega_1}$, we have an extra class, which we let represent $0$, and we let the linear orders $\phi \in LO$ of rank $n+1$ represent well-orders of rank $n$.)

But there is no Borel reduction at all from $E_{\omega_1}$ to $F_{\omega_1}$, or conversely. (Addendum: they are $\Delta^1_2$-bireducible, as described in Section 9.2.)

**Discussion** Su Gao gives this as an example of the fact that when the equivalence classes involved are not Borel, then Borel reducibility often seems inadequate to capture the notion of "definable reduction." Some weaker notions of reduction are "provably $\Delta^1_2$," or "$\Delta^1_2"$. See Section 9.2 of Su Gao.

Note that in general, when given two Borel representations $(\mathbb{R}, F)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, E)$ of the class of structures $H$, then presuming the maps $H / \cong \to \mathbb{R}/F$ and $H/ \cong \to \mathbb{R}/E$ are sufficiently definable in some sense, then there is a sufficiently definable bijection $\mathbb{R}/F \to \mathbb{R}/E$. So if there is no Borel such map, then no worries, we just figure out in what sense the representation *is* definable.

One can ask: what is the least restrictive notion of reduction that still allows a good theory? I'll put forward $HC$-reduction, defined in the paper [A New Notion of Cardinality for Countable First Order Theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05679), by myself, Richard Rast, and Chris Laskowski. (Here $HC$ is the set of hereditarily countable sets.)

Comment: This is very nice. Since as you noted your relations are not Borel, one naturally wonders whether there are such examples with Borel relations.

Comment: This is quite nice. Perhaps, one should add that Gao points out that there exists a $\Delta^1_2$ reduction from $F_{\omega_1}$ to $E_{\omega_1}$ (which is described in $\S 9.2$). It seems that $F_{\omega_1}$ codes countable linear orders in an "unnatural" way that obtaining the well order back in the other coding requires a non-Borel reduction. (Of course, one might argue that this coding is "natural" enough so that we should not believe in the proposed thesis.)

Comment: I edited the post to add that there is a $\Delta^1_2$ reduction

Comment: In my opinion, $\Delta^1_2$ is a far more powerful class than Borel. After all, the least transitive model of ZFC is $\Delta^1_2$ definable (if it exists), and so one has much more powerful methods in that class. Basically, $\Delta^1_2$ is huge.

Comment: I agree that $\Delta^1_2$ is huge... I guess in my mind the question of what reductions should be permitted is context-sensitive, with Borel being the most restrictive option (used in particular when the equivalence relations are Borel), and with provably $\Delta^1_2$ (and related things, like $HC$-reduction) being the least restrictive option. $\Delta^1_2$ is too big to be useful in $ZFC$--consistently (if $V=L$ say), there are $\Delta^1_2$ reductions from $(\mathbb{R}, E_{\omega_1})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, =)$, which is bad.

Comment: By the way, even though I was pleased learning this fact, I am not sure that $(LO,E_{\omega_1})$ is a "coding" in the sense that was meant in the proposed principle. The reason is that in this coding, we are representing countable well-orders as the quotient space $LO/E_{\omega_1}$, which is not standard Borel in the quotient Borel space structure. So I don't see any natural way of putting a standard Borel structure of $LO/E_{\omega_1}$. (This applies to the other coding as well.)

Comment: What is a quotient Borel space structure? Can you elaborate on what you want to happen? (Is this related to saying "$E_{\omega_1}$ is not a Borel equivalence relation?")

Comment: Well, you can declare $A \subseteq X/E$ to be Borel if $\cup A$ is Borel in $X$ for a standard Borel space $X$. However, this will not give you a standard Borel structure unless your relation is smooth. You can see the backwards direction of [Proposition 6.3](https://books.google.com/books?id=lzqKqFJX1YsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=topics+in+orbit+equivalence&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiT4N3gkPnLAhVL2hoKHYL4AA8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=proposition%206.3&f=false) here (where countability is not used). I will elaborate on what kind of examples I was looking for in the next comment.

Comment: In most of the examples that inspired this proposed thesis, we start with a collection of objects coding the structures we have and then put a standard Borel structure on them. Here, we start with LO and collapse LO-WO into a single class. In this case, the collection coding countable well orders is WO or $LO/E_{\omega_1}$ (whichever you like). What is the standard Borel structure on these collections? I don't see a reasonable way of putting one on the latter quotient space and the former space being a proper analytic set creates a problem for simply using the restriction.

Comment: I don't follow. As an example, consider $H = \mathcal{P}_{\aleph_1}(\mathbb{R})$, the set of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. There are a variety of nice Borel equivalence relations $E$ one can put on $\mathbb{R}$ to represent this, and they are all isomorphic. But what will be the Borel quotient space structure on $H$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37998/discussion-between-douglas-ulrich-and-burak).